# Rename xml filename using the value of an xml-node

Tags: xml, powershell, batch-file, rename

I already searched in the forum a way of renaming but I get all sorts of renaming and not the one needed.
Change the XML file name using one of the nodes via Batch file (or PowerShell. It is for Windows)

I have a XML file named PO_BLABLA01_XXX.XML and
I want to rename the file using a Batch File, making the file name being the PO Number "12345"

So having this content:

```
<Seller>
 <Name>POV AGING LIMITED</Name>
 <PO_No>12345</PO_NO>
 <AddressInfo>
   <agrlib:Address>ALBANY ROAD</agrlib:Address>
   <agrlib:Place>DESBOROUGH</agrlib:Place>
   <agrlib:Country>United Kingdom</agrlib:Country>
   <agrlib:Phone>9999-9999</agrlib:Phone>
 </AddressInfo>
 <VatRegNo>8888</VatRegNo>
 <BankAccount>7777</BankAccount>
</Seller>
```

I need my file to rename from "PO_BLABLA01_XXX.XML" to 12345.XML that is the value of the < PO_NO > field.

Can anyone point some light for me to follow :)
Thanks!

Comment: What OS? (This would be hard in `cmd.exe` but easy in PowerShell on Windows; other OSs have different shell scripts with different capabilities: without the target OS it is hard to help.)

Comment: Hi Richard. Its in Windows. Powershell can do as well. I thought we might achieve this with batch, but if not, PS can be. I just don;t know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using PowerShell

Once the XML is cleaned up (`<PO_No>` closing tag has different case; no namespace set for `agrlib` prefix):

```
[xml]$x = Get-Conent $InputFileName
$OutputFileName = $x.Seller.PN_No
Rename-Item -Path $InputFileNAme -NewName "$($OutputFileName).xml"
```

should do it.

Comment: Why do you use "$($OutputFileName).xml" instead of "$OutputFileName.xml"?

Comment: Thanks @Richard. I just posted part of the XML file to make my point and that's why it has some parts wrong ( I will clean it, too). I will have it a go right now and post the result :). Cheers!

Comment: @Swoogan Because I can never remember whether `.` is considered part of the identifier (like `:` is).

Comment: Using a real XML parser is the way to go, but if the XML isn't valid (undefined namespaces, e.g.), you should first fix that problem.

Comment: Dots are not part of identifiers (how would you distinguish a variable `$foo.bar` from a variable `$foo` with a property `bar` otherwise?). But even if they were, a subexpression wouldn't be required: `"${OutputFileName}.xml"` will suffice.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It is called: I don't write enough PSH to remember all the syntactic details, so I code conservatively. See KISS principle. (Also I used "identifier" in a non-precise way: in double quoted strings I could not recall if `$x.y` would be a property lookup on `$x` or `$x.ToString()` with `'.y'` appended.)

Comment: I meant to provide information, not to criticize. Sorry if my comment gave the wrong impression.

Answer (score 0):

If fixing the XML isn't an option (because PowerShell will totally balk at the undefined namespace and filtering out lines may be more work than solving the problem another way), **AND** (this is big) you can guarantee that the `PO_No` element will be on a line by itself like you've got it in the example, you could just grab that line and attempt to suck out the contents of the tag in a very unintelligent way:

```
FOR /F "delims=<> tokens=3" %%i IN ('findstr PO_No "%XML_FILE%"') DO RENAME "%XML_FILE%" "%%~i.xml"
```